# Update rows by reducing number of function calls to only once per row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE RM
SET RM.WEEK_1 = (
    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 1
),
RM.WEEK_2 = (
    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 2
),
RM.WEEK_3 = (
    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 3
),
RM.WEEK_4 = (
    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 4
),
RM.WEEK_5 = (
    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 5
),
RM.WEEK_6 = (
    SELECT P.AVERAGE_AVAI FROM dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P WHERE P.WEEKOFMONTH = 6
)
FROM @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1 RM
```

This works, but it's slow, because `dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage` is called for each week number. This function returns the same result for given `OPRO_KEY`. Basically it would be enough if this function is called only once per row (once for `OPRO_KEY`) and then results for each week would be updated from that table. Is it possible to do something like this? So, instead of calling this function for each week it's called only once per row and weeks are updated according to `WEEKOFMONTH`?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query and check the performance,

```
UPDATE  RM
SET     RM.WEEK_1   = (CASE WHEN WA.WEEKOFMONTH = 1 THEN WA.AVERAGE_AVAI ELSE RM.WEEK_1 END)
        ,RM.WEEK_2  = (CASE WHEN WA.WEEKOFMONTH = 2 THEN WA.AVERAGE_AVAI ELSE RM.WEEK_2 END)
        ,RM.WEEK_3  = (CASE WHEN WA.WEEKOFMONTH = 3 THEN WA.AVERAGE_AVAI ELSE RM.WEEK_3 END)
        ,RM.WEEK_4  = (CASE WHEN WA.WEEKOFMONTH = 4 THEN WA.AVERAGE_AVAI ELSE RM.WEEK_4 END)
        ,RM.WEEK_5  = (CASE WHEN WA.WEEKOFMONTH = 5 THEN WA.AVERAGE_AVAI ELSE RM.WEEK_5 END)
        ,RM.WEEK_6  = (CASE WHEN WA.WEEKOFMONTH = 6 THEN WA.AVERAGE_AVAI ELSE RM.WEEK_6 END)
FROM    @ROOMS_BY_DEPA_KEY1 RM
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT  P.AVERAGE_AVAI,P.WEEKOFMONTH
        FROM    dbo.f_SCAVAI_GetWeekAverage(RM.OPRO_KEY, @WEEKS_MONTH, @cWorkDaysOnly, RM.KAPACITETA) P 
    )   AS  WA
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't see any results for week numbers? Like nothing is updated.